# Get a list of variables in the global namespace in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

When writing Swift in the playground, I assume that variable written outside of any function or class are in some sort of global namespace.

For example if your playground looked like: 
http://swiftstub.com/26631088

```
var a = 0
for a in 1...5 {
    print(a)
}

var b = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(b)

var c = CGPoint()
print(c.x,c.y)
```

Is it possible to get a list of variables in the global namespace?

In this example I would want: `a`,`b`,`c`. Maybe get them in an array, or a dictionary, or any type of list/sequence? So that this can be done dynamically, not manually.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know of any other languages where this is possible?

Comment: @Arc676 I believe it would be possible in Javascript, because each global variable is on the `window` object. You could loop through the `window` properties, even through there would be many other properties on the `window` object.